# How to display Dynamic table using Asp .net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, uitableview, razor, view, datatables

I'm Working with Asp .net MVC3.I'm displaying a table in front end.I'm using a stored procedure to populate the table table columns will be populated dynamically.For example i have contains id,name,chk1,chk2,chk3 columns the stored procedure populates table where columns of the table will be populated dynamically.how can i handle this situation in view page.

following is my view ,

```
     <table>
<tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.colName)
{
    <th>@item.column_name</th>
} 
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model.bgv)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.id</td>
        <td>@item.name</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlchk", new SelectList  (Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status","Validation_Status"))</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlchk", new SelectList(Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status","Validation_Status"))</td>
        <td>@Html.DropDownList("ddlchk", new SelectList(Model.dd, "Validation_Code", "Validation_Status","Validation_Status"))</td>
          </tr>
    }    
  </table>
```

This works correct when stored procedure return value for all(id,name,chk1,chk2,chk3) the columns.when SP returns id,name,chk1,chk2 columns it shows td with no header?how i can handile this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.colName)
        {
           <th>@item.column_name</th>
        } 
    </tr>
</thead>
```